# Angular 2 - Favicons Webpack Plugin injecting html in many files

Tags: angular, webpack

Apparently the plugin injects the html page in every file, even .js files, images...every file... which renders the application unusable

how do I tell the plugin to only do the injection in index.html?

- angular: ^5.2.0 -> 5.2.10
- ng CLI: ~1.7.4 -> 1.7.4
- tslint: ~5.9.1 -> 5.9.1
- typescript: ~2.5.3 -> 2.5.3
- webpack: ~3.11.0 -> 3.11.0

Here is the webpack config I use (generated by ng cli)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const postcssImports = require('postcss-import');

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, EnvironmentPlugin, HashedModuleIdsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin, SuppressExtractedTextChunksWebpackPlugin, CleanCssWebpackPlugin, BundleBudgetPlugin, PostcssCliResources } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin, ModuleConcatenationPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { LicenseWebpackPlugin } = require('license-webpack-plugin');
const { PurifyPlugin } = require('@angular-devkit/build-optimizer');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const realNodeModules = fs.realpathSync(nodeModules);
const genDirNodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', '$$_gendir', 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles","vendor","main"];
const hashFormat = {"chunk":".[chunkhash:20]","extract":".[contenthash:20]","file":".[hash:20]","script":".[hash:20]"};
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";
const projectRoot = process.cwd();
const maximumInlineSize = 10;
const postcssPlugins = function (loader) {
        return [
            postcssImports({
                resolve: (url, context) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        let hadTilde = false;
                        if (url && url.startsWith('~')) {
                            url = url.substr(1);
                            hadTilde = true;
                        }
                        loader.resolve(context, (hadTilde ? '' : './') + url, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                if (hadTilde) {
                                    reject(err);
                                    return;
                                }
                                loader.resolve(context, url, (err, result) => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        reject(err);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        resolve(result);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                resolve(result);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                },
                load: (filename) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        loader.fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                                return;
                            }
                            const content = data.toString();
                            resolve(content);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }),
            postcssUrl({
                filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('~'),
                url: ({ url }) => {
                    const fullPath = path.join(projectRoot, 'node_modules', url.substr(1));
                    return path.relative(loader.context, fullPath).replace(/\\/g, '/');
                }
            }),
            postcssUrl([
                {
                    // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                    filter: ({ url }) => url.startsWith('/') && !url.startsWith('//'),
                    url: ({ url }) => {
                        if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//) || deployUrl.startsWith('/')) {
                            // If deployUrl is absolute or root relative, ignore baseHref & use deployUrl as is.
                            return `${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${url}`;
                        }
                        else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                            // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                            return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                                `/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                        }
                        else {
                            // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                            // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                            return `/${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${url}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // TODO: inline .cur if not supporting IE (use browserslist to check)
                    filter: (asset) => {
                        return maximumInlineSize > 0 && !asset.hash && !asset.absolutePath.endsWith('.cur');
                    },
                    url: 'inline',
                    // NOTE: maxSize is in KB
                    maxSize: maximumInlineSize,
                    fallback: 'rebase',
                },
                { url: 'rebase' },
            ]),
            PostcssCliResources({
                deployUrl: loader.loaders[loader.loaderIndex].options.ident == 'extracted' ? '' : deployUrl,
                loader,
                filename: `[name]${hashFormat.file}.[ext]`,
            }),
            autoprefixer({ grid: true }),
        ];
    };




module.exports = {
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "symlinks": true,
    "modules": [
      "./src",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "alias": rxPaths(),
    "mainFields": [
      "browser",
      "module",
      "main"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "alias": rxPaths()
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src\\polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./src\\styles.css"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].[chunkhash:20].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].[chunkhash:20].chunk.js",
    "crossOriginLoading": false
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
          "limit": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader",
        "options": {
          "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
          "limit": 10000
        }
      },
      {
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "cache-loader",
            "options": {
              "cacheDirectory": "********"
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "precision": 8,
              "includePaths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
              "ident": "embedded",
              "plugins": postcssPlugins,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false,
              "paths": []
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "raw-loader"
    },
    {
      "loader": "postcss-loader",
      "options": {
        "ident": "extracted",
        "plugins": postcssPlugins,
        "sourceMap": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "raw-loader"
    },
    {
      "loader": "postcss-loader",
      "options": {
        "ident": "extracted",
        "plugins": postcssPlugins,
        "sourceMap": false
      }
    },
    {
      "loader": "sass-loader",
      "options": {
        "sourceMap": false,
        "precision": 8,
        "includePaths": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "raw-loader"
    },
    {
      "loader": "postcss-loader",
      "options": {
        "ident": "extracted",
        "plugins": postcssPlugins,
        "sourceMap": false
      }
    },
    {
      "loader": "less-loader",
      "options": {
        "sourceMap": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "raw-loader"
    },
    {
      "loader": "postcss-loader",
      "options": {
        "ident": "extracted",
        "plugins": postcssPlugins,
        "sourceMap": false
      }
    },
    {
      "loader": "stylus-loader",
      "options": {
        "sourceMap": false,
        "paths": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "test": /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
        "use": [
          {
            "loader": "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/webpack-loader",
            "options": {
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "@ngtools/webpack"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "assets\\**\\*",
          "dot": true
        }
      },
      {
        "context": "src",
        "to": "",
        "from": {
          "glob": "favicon.ico",
          "dot": true
        }
      }
    ], {
      "ignore": [
        ".gitkeep",
        "**/.DS_Store",
        "**/Thumbs.db"
      ],
      "debug": "warning"
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      "exclude": /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/,
      "failOnError": false,
      "onDetected": false,
      "cwd": projectRoot
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src\\index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": false,
      "minify": {
        "caseSensitive": true,
        "collapseWhitespace": true,
        "keepClosingSlash": true
      },
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightIndex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": [
        "inline"
      ],
      "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": [
        "main"
      ],
      "minChunks": 2,
      "async": "common"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      "filename": "[name].[contenthash:20].bundle.css"
    }),
    new SuppressExtractedTextChunksWebpackPlugin(),
    new CleanCssWebpackPlugin(),
    new EnvironmentPlugin({
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }),
    new HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
      "hashFunction": "md5",
      "hashDigest": "base64",
      "hashDigestLength": 4
    }),
    new ModuleConcatenationPlugin({}),
    new BundleBudgetPlugin({}),
    /*new LicenseWebpackPlugin({
      "licenseFilenames": [
        "LICENSE",
        "LICENSE.md",
        "LICENSE.txt",
        "license",
        "license.md",
        "license.txt"
      ],
      "perChunkOutput": false,
      "outputTemplate": path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\license-webpack-plugin\\output.template.ejs"),
      "outputFilename": "3rdpartylicenses.txt",
      "suppressErrors": true,
      "includePackagesWithoutLicense": false,
      "abortOnUnacceptableLicense": false,
      "addBanner": false,
      "bannerTemplate": "/*! 3rd party license information is available at <%- filename %> * /",
      "includedChunks": [],
      "excludedChunks": [],
      "additionalPackages": [],
      "modulesDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "pattern": /^(MIT|ISC|BSD.*)$/
    }),*/
    new PurifyPlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      "test": /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
      "extractComments": false,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "cache": true,
      "parallel": true,
      "uglifyOptions": {
        "output": {
          "ascii_only": true,
          "comments": false,
          "webkit": true
        },
        "ecma": 5,
        "warnings": false,
        "ie8": false,
        "mangle": {
          "safari10": true
        },
        "compress": {
          "typeofs": false,
          "inline": 3,
          "pure_getters": true,
          "passes": 3
        }
      }
    }),
    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "platform": 0,
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.prod.ts"
      },
      "sourceMap": false,
      "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
      "compilerOptions": {}
    }),
exports["plugins"].push(
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
            // Your source logo
            logo: './src/assets/images/edenred-monogram.png',
            // The prefix for all image files (might be a folder or a name)
            prefix: 'icons.[hash].'+releaseNumber+'./',
            // Emit all stats of the generated icons
            emitStats: false,
            // The name of the json containing all favicon information
            statsFilename: 'iconstats-[hash].json',
            // Generate a cache file with control hashes and
            // don't rebuild the favicons until those hashes change
            persistentCache: true,
            // Inject the html into the html-webpack-plugin
            inject: true,
            // favicon background color (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
            background: '#fff',
            // favicon app title (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
            title: 'Webpack App',
            // which icons should be generated (see https://github.com/haydenbleasel/favicons#usage)
            icons: {
              android: true,
              appleIcon: true,
              appleStartup: true,
              coast: false,
              favicons: true,
              firefox: true,
              opengraph: false,
              twitter: false,
              yandex: false,
              windows: false
            }
      })
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  },
  "devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true
  }
};
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

answer is simple

this comes along the huge pile of plugins not maintained anymore